# How to set PWN_ON high?

Tags: pic, robotics, mplab

I have a project where I have to use an ultra sonic sensor URM37 V3.2 
there is an instruction in the [data sheet](http://www.daedalus.ei.tum.de/attachments/article/186/URM3.2%20DFROBOT%20Ultraschalltransceiver.pdf) that say : " `PWN_ON must be set to high to enable sensor`".

So please, can anyone help me on how to set `PWN_ON` as high ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [datasheet](http://www.daedalus.ei.tum.de/attachments/article/186/URM3.2%20DFROBOT%20Ultraschalltransceiver.pdf), one of the pin of the module (number 7) is named `PWR_ON`. It is described as :

> > > 7: PWR_ON - Enable pin, enable the sensor when high

My guess is there is a typo in the datasheet !

To enable the sensor, this pin must be set to VCC=+5V...by using a wire...

There are places in the Stackexchange network where this question would have been answered within a few minutes : [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) or [Robotics](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/).